# How to set up app-ads.txt for your apps for Free

Tags: android, admob, subdomain, web-hosting

I got a message:

**Add or update app-ads.txt**

*Your app-ads.txt file is either missing or not valid. To prevent a significant loss in ad revenue, add or update your app-ads.txt.*

*Publish your app-ads.txt on the root of your developer website (for example, sampledomain.com/app-ads.txt). Make sure that the domain is entered exactly as listed on Google Play or the App Store.*

I don't have a developer website.

**My Requirement:** How to setup this app-ads.txt file ***for free***? (I've no domain or website)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Blog in https://www.blogger.com/

click on settings and then in **Monetization** switch on Enable custom ads.txt

In **Errors and redirects** click on Custom redirects and add app-ads.txt and then click save

Comment: Can you provide more information about the last step? On that page there are options to add "from/" and "to/" and a permanent switch.

Also, nowhere in these instructions does it explain where to edit or upload the .txt file?

Comment: add your app-ads.text content to Custom ads txt under monetization and and add custom redirect to it
From: /app-ads.txt
To: /ads.txt
Permanent: Yes

Comment: @OzgurSahin Your comment is a life savior, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a clarification to [Waqar Khan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66949912/7883681)

1. In your blog (from Blogger), go to **settings**.
2. In **Monetization** section, switch on enable custom ads.txt
3. Then in **Errors and redirects** section, click on Custom redirects ---> add ---> In the following dialog, input these:

   `From: /app-ads.txt`  `To: /ads.txt` `Permanent: Yes`
4. Click save. And that's set.
5. Try now going to **your_blog_domin/app-ads.txt**

Answer (score 1):

Firebase also offers a free way to host your app-ads.txt file https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9820295?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, already solved with Blogger. If I've time, I will go through, this. I've an Firebase Android App as Free Plan. Is this feature available in Free Plan?